# Solving a bilinear form equation over a cubic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a cyclic cubic field, i.e., $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois cubic extension. Consider the bilinear form defined on $K^2$ by

$$\displaystyle \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = 2 x_2 y_0 - x_1 y_1 + 2 x_0 y_2,$$

where $\mathbf{x} = (x_0, x_1, x_2)$ and $\mathbf{y} = (y_2, y_1, y_0)$.

Is there a solution to the equation

$$\displaystyle \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{y} = 0$$

with entries of $\mathbf{x}$ being conjugates of the entries of $\mathbf{y}$?

Comment: Is there a reason for the indices of $(x_0, x_1, x_2)$ and of $(y_2, y_1, y_0)$ to go in opposite order? And which one of them is the $\Bbb Q$-coordinate?

Comment: @Arthur the opposite order arises from the natural structure of the question I am concerned with... I don't think it affects the present problem. If it bothers you you can certainly flip the order. I am also not choosing a basis... so there is no $\mathbb{Q}$-coordinate necessarily

Comment: the part about the opposite order fits well with Fricke and Klein (1897 I think) where every isotropic ternary quadratic form over $\mathbb Q$ is related to $y^2 - z x.$ This is related to discriminants of binary quadratic forms, the discriminant of $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ being $b^2 - 4 a c.$ Some of this is discussed in Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms, pages 301-303. Not sure where to look for more general fields. Do you have any examples?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=H5kLAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Vorlesungen+%C3%BCber+die+Theorie+der+automorphen++Functionen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIscb4rNvYxgIVSCiICh3qMwQX#v=onepage&q=muesli&f=false  The particular item I have in mind is pages  507-508, within the text, not stated as a separate theorem in the modern style.

Comment: in the new English translation, the appropriate section is now pages 409-412  https://bookstore.ams.org/ctm-3/

Answer (score 1):

As a ternary quadratic form, your item is isotropic; there are null vectors $\vec{x} = \vec{y}$

Just so you know, and before adjusting for the coefficient 4, the parametrization of integer primitive solutions to $y^2 - zx = 0$ are just
$$ x = u^2 \; , \; \; y = uv \; , \; \; z = v^2  $$
for coprime $u,v$

You might be able to do something with that in your cubic field, not sure. As I commented, as a quadratic form your thing resembles  $y^2 - 4zx = 0,$ so look at
$$ x = u^2 \; , \; \; y = 2uv \; , \; \; z = v^2  $$

Comment: Yes I am aware that the form is soluble over $\mathbb{Q}$... and hence also soluble over any field of characteristic 0. However, the condition that the two solutions have to be conjugate seems quite strict. Nevertheless, examples can be constructed to show that solutions usually exist (in fact, for any such cubic field one can construct such a solution)

Comment: @syxiao Fair enough. I was hoping the parametrization for the quadratic form version would do you some good, but I guess not.